# Why do Images change quality after animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a jquery image slider which slides images on a div ('class=container') on my webpage and a Logo image (in .png format) image found on a seperate div  ('id=logo').

when the image slider slides the images on the '.container' div ,
in other words when the image on top has been animated and the next image shows up

the image on the #logo div magically loses its quality and even contains rugged edges almost as if it was originaly a low quality image

[take a look here](http://postimg.org/image/ru02maz5f/f9defe45)  
I don't know wether its the jquery causing this or if it is the css 
i am using for the image .

this is the jquery code I used for the sliding effect div.

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $(".container > div:gt(0)").hide();
    var count=0;
    setInterval(function() { 
       $('.container > div:first')
          .animate({right:"110%"}) 
          .fadeOut(1000)
          .animate({right:"-110%"})
          .next()
          .fadeIn(1000)
          .end()
          .appendTo('.container');                 
       },  4000);
```

});

and this is the css of the logo div (the div that contains my logo.png image)

```
#logo{  opacity:0.8;        
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:36%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
} 

#logo img{

     max-width: 400px;
     max-height: 200px;
```

}

Comment: Please create a sandbox demo that replicates problem. There isn't enough information provided here

Comment: Please re-read it again . Ithink it's more understandable now.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or a snippet with the images you are using that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Please view this image here [link]http://postimg.org/image/ru02maz5f/f9defe45/

Comment: can you recreate in a fiddle. also, your setting width, what are the original image dimensions?